# Comparing two regex in Javascript and getting weird results

Tags: javascript

Can someone please explain this strange behavior in Javascript? When I do comparisons using the `match()` method I don't get the expected result.

```
var mat_1 = "wpawn";
var mat_2 = "wRook";

//compare both; do they have the same first letter? 

alert(mat_1.match(/^\w/) + " seems equal to " + mat_2.match(/^\w/));
if (mat_1.match(/^\w/) === mat_2.match(/^\w/)) {
    alert("They are really equal")
}

//another approach

if (mat_1[0] === mat_2[0]) {
    alert("Yes! Equals")
}
```

Comment: `match` produces an array, not a string.

Answer (score 1):

`match` produces an array.  You should really  use an array comparison function, but for the sake of simple demonstration, try this - the first match value is selected and compared.  All 3 alerts are triggered:

```js
var mat_1 = "wpawn";
var mat_2 = "wRook";

//compare both; do they have the same first letter? 

alert(mat_1.match(/^\w/)+" seems equal to "+mat_2.match(/^\w/));
if(mat_1.match(/^\w/)[0] === mat_2.match(/^\w/)[0]){alert("They are really equal")}

//another approach

if(mat_1[0] === mat_2[0]){alert("Yes! Equals")}
```

Comment: Humm... that makes sense to me now. Thanks for the answer, man! I can get some sleep now. This puzzle was driving me crazy.

Answer (score 1):

Match returns an array of matches:

```
String.prototype.match(pattern: Regex): Array<string>
```

Your first evaluation will always fail as you are comparing two arrays.

This is the correct way for what you are trying to achieve.

```
'myWord'.match(/^\w/)[0] == 'mIsTeRy'.match(/^\w/)[0]
```

Although if you wanna truly use the regex to check the first letter, I wouldn't recommend it. Too much overhead for something too trivial (just my two cents).

Have fun coding! :)

Comment: Thank you! Very nice answer!

Comment: @Peristiloperis everyone has a hard time from now and then, helping just makes progress truly happen, so you are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

in the following lines of code you are checking the variables `mat_1` and `mat_2` for whether both the words starts with `'w'`, btw `match()` returns an array

```
if (mat_1.match(/^\w/) === mat_2.match(/^\w/)) {
    alert("They are really equal")
}
```

you can try something like

```
if (["w"] === ["w"]) {
    console.log("seems equal");
} else {
    console.log("not equal");
}
```

for array comparison you can check this **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)**

what you have to do here is

```
if (["w"][0] === ["w"][0]) { // match for the elements in the array
    console.log("seems equal");
} else {
    console.log("not equal");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Avi! You guys are aewsome!

Comment: glad we could help :)